# Python inheritance default values from the parents class

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have two classes:

```
class Media:
def __init__(self, title="No Title", author="No Author", release_year="No Release Year", url="No URL"):
    self.title = title
    self.author = author
    self.release_year = release_year
    self.url = url

class Song(Media):
def __init__(self, title, author, release_year, url, album="No Album", genre="No Genre", track_length=0):
    super().__init__(title, author, release_year, url)
    self.album = album
    self.genre = genre
    self.track_length = track_length
```

Then I try to create an object

```
mySong = Song()
```

And I got an error saying that `TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'title', 'author', 'release_year', and 'url'`

Is there a way to inherit the default values from the parents class? Like we can pass the "No Title" from the Media class to the Song class

And if I only provide part of the information, can we combine it together, for example if I create a new object

```
newSong = Song(author="justin bieber")
```

and try

```
print(newSong.author)
print(newSong.url)
```

I wish it will show Justin bieber and No URL.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work like this. What you can do, you can let passing some number of kwargs and get possible parameters for parent class from them:

```
   class Song(Media):
    def __init__(self, album="No Album", genre="No Genre", track_length=0, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(kwargs.get('title', None), kwargs.get('author', None), kwargs.get('release_year', None), kwargs.get('url', None))
        self.album = album
        self.genre = genre
        self.track_length = track_length
```

Answer (score 0):

No don't can because you Override the constructor ( `__init__` ) method but can use of *args or **kwd

> And if I only provide part of the information, can we combine it together, for example if I create a new object

NO , information must be full or have default & the second part is Yes

```py
class Name(Parent):
      def __init__(self,title="No", url="No"):
                  self.title = title
                  if url.lower() == "no":
                               self.url = url
                  else :
                        self.url = url
```